# installing node.js after apt-get install node

Tags: ubuntu, installation, node.js

Im trying to install `node.js` and I made the mistake of installing `apt-get install node`. Which is not `node.js`.

I'm able to find the right `node.js` on git hub, build and make everything. Everything seems to be installed. But I get this error when executing `node -v`

```
~/node$ node -v
-bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to make `node -v` work?

Also, on ubuntu 10.04 if it helps

Comment: what shell, try `rehash` to rescan the completion directories. Also if you are in the directory where the binary is and it isn't in your path.  try ./node -v

Comment: yes, i can get node to run by doing `/usr/local/bin/node node -v`.. tho i'd like to be able to run it using simply `node -v`

Comment: do you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`? (type `echo $PATH` to test)

Answer (score 53):

it looks like you removed(uninstalled) node from /usr/sbin, just make sure that /usr/local/bin in in your path and run

bash: `hash -r`

zsh: `rehash`

And your shell should pick up the new location, and run it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since [CTTE #614907](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html) you're simply supposed to `apt-get install nodejs` and proceed further by confirming the removal of the `node` package.  You've gotta choose one over the other because of the name conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You need to purge node *and* related packages:

> sudo apt-get purge node
>
> sudo apt-get purge